# Adicionar vários itens em uma única session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Dessa forma eu adiciono um item na `session`

```
 var item = new FornecedorTipoFrete()
            {

                TipoFreteId = id,
                TipoFrete = new TipoFrete() { Descricao = tipofrete },
                FornecedorId = (fornecedorID)
            };

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("TipoFreteId", id.ToString());
```

Porém esse processo pode ocorrer várias vezes.
 O usuário pode adicionar vários TiposFretes, então poderia ser um ou vários, como posso adicionar todos e depois ler essa sessão com vários itens.

**EDIT**

Eu tentei fazendo desta forma:
Adicionei esta linha no `controller`

`IList<string> listaFrete = new List<string>();`

e então para salvar na `Session` fiz desta forma:

```
listaFrete.Add(id.ToString());
            HttpContext.Session.SetObject("Lista", listaFrete);
```

Porém ele sempre pega o último, não vai salvando na lista. Sempre fica apenas um item, sempre o último.

Comment: não pode adicionar um array ou list de "TipoFreteId"?

Comment: A forma hoje aceita apenas um TipoFreteId, o usuário vai poder incluir vários, e só vai salvar quando for realizado o submit, se não for ocorrer problemas, pode.

Comment: então acho que pode resolver.. só vai dar um trabalho a mais tratar a lista, e talvez remover /adicionar itens dependendo se tiver alterações

Comment: Eu preciso adicionar, adiciono via Json, e pra excluir também excluiria via Json.

Comment: se tiver muita manutenção talvez a session não seja o melhor lugar, quem sabe um banco seja melhor

Comment: Nesse caso, é pq o usuário vai incluir para salvar, ele pode incluir e decidir não terminar o cadastro. Teria alguma forma melhor de se fazer?

Comment: A session pode perder se ele fechar o navegador ou pode expirar.. uma possibilidade seria salvar numa tabela "temporaria" ou se se tiver no seu ambiente um banco noSQL por exemplo.. são opções

Comment: No caso acho que seria melhor a sessão mesmo.

Comment: Usa cookies se este é o caso. Mas ainda se preferir usar session sugiro gravar uma lista ou array do item na session

Comment: @RicardoPontual editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro é o seu método que você praticamente já utiliza para adicionar a session, e segudo o método que usará para buscar um item na lista armazenada na `Session`.

```js
void AddItemSession()
{
  var item = new FornecedorTipoFrete()
  {

    TipoFreteId = id,
    TipoFrete = new TipoFrete() { Descricao = tipofrete },
    FornecedorId = (fornecedorID)
  };

  List<FornecedorTipoFrete> lstFornecedorTipoFrete = new List<FornecedorTipoFrete>();

  if (Session["ListaTipoFrete"] != null)
        lstFornecedorTipoFrete = (List<FornecedorTipoFrete>)Session["ListaTipoFrete"];
        
  lstFornecedorTipoFrete.Add(item);
  Session["ListaTipoFrete"] = lstFornecedorTipoFrete;
}

FornecedorTipoFrente ReturnFornecedorTipoFrete(string tipoFreteId)
{
  if (Session["ListaTipoFrete"] == null)
    return null;

  return (Session["ListaTipoFrete"] as List<FornecedorTipoFrete>).FirstOrDefault(c=> c.TipoFreteId == tipoFreteId);
}
```

Comment: Eu não tenho a opção de `Session`, utilizo asp.net core, ele informa que não existe Session no contexto atual

Comment: Usa o HttpContext.Session.SetString() então e seta um json usando JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value). A lógica é a mesma.

Comment: Eu tentei adicionando essa linha no controller `IList<string> listaFrete = new List<string>();` e então fazendo assim pra pegar o valor. `listaFrete.Add(id.ToString());
                HttpContext.Session.SetObject("Lista", listaFrete);` mas ele sempre substituiu, e não inclui na lista.

Comment: Entao seta sempre em uma string só separando os ids por "," (Vírgula). Ex: "1,17,9". sempre buscando a informação e dando .Split(',') obtendo como retorno um array de ids.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, de como estou tentando fazer.

Comment: Ele está ficando sempre o último não é porque sempre cria uma nova lista? IList<string> listaFrete = new List<string>();

Comment: Eu não criei dentro da função. Será que mesmo assim está sendo executado?

Comment: Eu apenas declarei assim `IList<int> listaFrete;` e dentro da função faço dessa forma: `if (listaFrete == null)
                {
                    listaFrete = new List<int>();
                }` porém ele sempre está retornando `null`

Comment: coloquei com `static` e deu certo, obrigado.